# How to read KML file

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

I have KML file and I want to read this file and to do some changes in the KML in run time  ( to create the coordinates and then to update the map ) and then to show it in Google maps.

How I can read the KML file to my application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an alternative KML parser, eg
http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/

(geoxml3 is now on GitHub: https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3)

Comment: But I want to do some calculation before I will see the point in screen. As far as I understood if I will use this parser it will show the point without any calculation

Comment: It's open source. You download the file and host it on your server, and because it's on your server can modify it...