# Develop a KML layer with specifying KML file content as string only?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We can develop a KML layer as follows:

```
var crosshairLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('KML File PATH');
crosshairLayer.setMap(map);
```

For this we have to upload a kml file somewhere on internet and then we have to pass kml file URL in the new google.maps.KmlLayer('KML File PATH') constructor.

Can we develop KML Layer specifying KML content only. I dont want to upload the KML file somewhere and then using its URL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read KML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028584/how-to-read-kml-file)

Answer (score 1):

The [geoxml3 parser](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) has a parseKmlString method which takes a string containing valid KML and parses it to produce native Google Maps API v3 objects (so you lose the benefit of tile based rendering you get with KmlLayer, whether that will be efficient enough will depend on how complex your KML is).

Answer (score 0):

The api does not support this directly. You'll need to use a 3rd party kml parser. See [How to read KML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028584/how-to-read-kml-file/11034938)